# How to solve Newton's Cooling Law using Runge-Kutta method (RK4)

Tags: java, for-loop, math, runge-kutta

I need help implementing my working 4th-Order Runge-Kutta method for solving Newton's Cooling Law. Since time (t) is introduced with this problem, I am confused on the placings for the given conditions.  Here is what's given: time interval begins t = 0 to t = 20 (in seconds), object temp = 300, ambient temp = 70, time increment is .1, and constant of proportionality = 0.19

```
public class RungeKutta {

public static double NewtonsCoolingLaw(double objectTemp,double  ambientTemp)
     {
         double k = 0.19;       
         return -k * (objectTemp - ambientTemp);
     }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double result = 0.0;  
    double  initialObjectTemp = 300.0, givenAmbientTemp = 70.0;
    double deltaX = (20.0 - 0)/10000;

    for(double t = 0.0; t <= 20.0; t += .1)
    {        
        double k1 = deltaX * NewtonsLaw(initialObjectTemp,givenAmbientTemp);
        double k2 = deltaX * NewtonsLaw(initialObjectTemp + (deltaX/2.0),givenAmbientTemp + (k1/2.0));
        double k3 = deltaX * NewtonsLaw(initialObjectTemp + (deltaX/2.0), givenAmbientTemp + (k2/2.0));
        double k4 = deltaX * NewtonsLaw(initialObjectTemp + deltaX, givenAmbientTemp + k3);
        givenAmbientTemp = givenAmbientTemp + (1.0/6.0) * (k1 + (2.0 * k2) + (2.0 * k3) + k4);
        result = givenAmbientTemp;
    }       
    System.out.println("The approx. object temp after 20 seconds is: " + result);

}

}
```

Bellow is my RK4 method for solving ODEs. In the code below, I solve the ODE y' = y - x to approximate y(1.005) given that y(1) = 10 and delta x = 0.001

```
public class RungeKutta {

public static double functionXnYn(double x,double  y)
     {
         return y-x;
     }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double deltaX = (1.005 - 0)/10000;
    double y = 10.0;
    double result = 0.0;  

    for(double x = 1.0; x <= 1.005; x = x + deltaX)
    {
        double k1 = deltaX * functionXnYn(x,y);
        double k2 = deltaX * functionXnYn(x + (deltaX/2.0),y + (k1/2.0));
        double k3 = deltaX * functionXnYn(x + (deltaX/2.0), y + (k2/2.0));
        double k4 = deltaX * functionXnYn(x + deltaX, y + k3);
        y = y + (1.0/6.0) * (k1 + (2.0 * k2) + (2.0 * k3) + k4);
        result = y;
    }       
    System.out.println("The value of y(1.005) is: " + result);

}

}
```

Based on the formula T(t) = Ts + (T0 - Ts) * e^(-k*t) I should have an approximation of 75.1 for solving Newton's DE. Ts = ambient temp, T0 = object initial temp, t = 20 (seconds elapsed), and k = .19 constant of proportionality

Comment: What's the error? Could you give some examples of expected and actual output for some values of deltaX and y?

Comment: Is the ambient temperature meant to be constant or is the outer volume small enough that it also changes with time? Object and outer volume are assumed to be homogeneous, no spacial resolution of the cooling process is desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing (but not really hard) that the ODE you are trying to solve is

```
dT(t)/dt = -k*(T(t)-T_amb)
```

As you can see, the right side does not directly depend on the time.
As you make no attempts to code for a system, it is likely that the ambient temperature `T_amb` is a constant. Thus moving the constants around and using consistent function names and returning the ODE function arguments to the format `time, state variable`

```
public class RungeKutta {

    public static double CoolingLaw(double time, double objectTemp)
         {
             double k = 0.19, ambientTemp = 70.0;     
             return -k * (objectTemp - ambientTemp);
         }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double result = 0.0;  
        double  objectTemp = 300.0;
        double dt = 0.1

        for(double t = 0.0; t <= 20.0; t += dt)
        {        
            double k1 = dt * CoolingLaw(t, objectTemp);
            double k2 = dt * CoolingLaw(t + (dt/2.0), objectTemp + (k1/2.0));
            double k3 = dt * CoolingLaw(t + (dt/2.0), objectTemp + (k2/2.0));
            double k4 = dt * CoolingLaw(t + dt, objectTemp + k3);
            objectTemp = objectTemp + (1.0/6.0) * (k1 + (2.0 * k2) + (2.0 * k3) + k4);
            result = objectTemp;
        }       
        System.out.println("The approx. object temp after 20 seconds is: " + result);

    }


}
```